# Java validation sc.next(); method

Tags: java, validation

I'm trying to create a solid validation process and the only thing i can't understand it's sc.next(); method. Without this method i can't redirect user back to the scanner input. Please, explain, what this method is actually working for?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    int a;
    int b;

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter two integer digits");
        while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("An error has occured. Enter two integer digits");
            input.next(); // What this method is actually working for?
        }
        a = input.nextInt();
        b = input.nextInt();
    } while (a == 0 && b == 0);
}
```

}

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--

Answer (score 0):

The call to `input.next();` is used to consume the user input as `hasNextInt()` does not make the scanner advance past any input, therefore, meaning you'll have an *infinite* loop if a user enters anything other than an integer. put it simply the call `input.next();` is used to consume and discard the input in this specific case.